# How to pad an integer with zeroes to the right of the integer?

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I know that to pad an integer with zeroes I can do the following,

NSString *version = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03d", appVersion.intValue];

This will add up to 3 zeroes to the left of the integer if needed. However I would like to do the same but instead of padding to the left, I need to pad to the right.

How can I pad an integer with zeroes but to the right of the integer? (Ideally with similar simplicity as the above method)

Here's an example of what I need,

If the integer turns out to be 38, I need the version string to come out as 380 (Only one zero was added to the end of the integer because I wanted a max of three characters and if the integer is less than three characters, zeroes will be added to make it three).

The method I am currently using will give me 038. I need 380.

Or if the integer is 381 then the output should be 381 because I only want a max of three character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you multiply the value by 1000, and then print that? If you need a lot of zeroes, you might generally want to promote the `int` to a `long` or `long long` before multiplying, to reduce the likelihood of overflow.

```
NSString *version = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", ((long)appVersion.intValue)*1000];
```

If you need the length of the `int` in digits, before deciding to multiply by some factor of ten, take the `floor` of the decimal `log` of the value and add one. For example:

```
int foo = 123;
int digitsInFoo = floor(log10(foo)) + 1; /* 3 */
```

Then use some rule to decide how many zero digits to add.

```
int totalDesiredLength = 5;
int numberOfZeroesNeeded = totalDesiredLength - digitsInFoo; /* this assumes totalDesiredLength >= digitsInFoo */
int factor = (int) pow(10, numberOfZeroesNeeded); /* 100 */
```

Then the five-digit result will be `foo * factor` or `12300`. You can adjust this for your situation as needed. Test for bounds so that you don't end up with weird results.

Comment: Unless the amount of digits is known and fixed, this method will require some extra conditions to format it to the size/length OP wants. But this is a way to go.

Comment: The problem with this method is that I want a maximum of three characters including the integer. So for example if the integer ends up being 38 then your method give me 38000 when I need 380. And likewise if the integer ends up being 381 then the output should be 381 no need to pad with zeroes in this case because I have the maximum of three characters I need.

Comment: I edited my answer to address this point. You just need to pick the value of `totalDesiredLength` that works for your needs. Be sure to check bounds.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it looks pretty elegant and simple. However what do you mean by test for bounds?

Comment: Make sure numberOfZeroesNeeded is positive, make sure you pick a type that won't overflow with the values you're working with, etc.

Comment: Oh I see. Well anyways thanks a lot for the answer. It's working great.

Answer (score 0):

```
char buf[4];
int len = sprintf(buf, "%u", 38);
while (len < 3)
    buf[len++] = '0';
buf[len] = '\0';
```

You might prefer `sprint_s` over `sprintf`. And if you're really paranoid, check that the value returned from `sprintf` isn't negative.

Comment: What if `buf` needs to be longer or shorter than three characters (without null character)?

Comment: Then you have a different question, which might have a different answer. But the answer is simple: make it as large as you need.